# program exhibiting bizarre behavior when reading words out from a file

Tags: perl

So I have two files, one that contains my text, and another which I want to contain filter words. The one shown here is supposed to be the one with the curse words. Basically, what I'm doing is iterating through each of the words in the text file, and trying to compare them against the curse words.

```
sub filter {
    $word_to_check = $_;

    open ( FILE2, $ARGV[1]) || die "Something went wrong. \n";

    while(<FILE2>) {
            @cursewords = split;
            foreach $curse (@cursewords) {
                    print $curse."\n";
                    if($word_to_check eq $curse) { return "BAD!";}
            }
    }
    close ( FILE2 );
}
```

Here are the "curse words":

```
what is
```

Here is the text file:

```
hey dude what is up
```

But here's what's going wrong. As you can see, I've put a print statement to see if the curse words are getting checked correctly.

```
hey what
is
dude what
is
what what
is
is what
is
up what
is
```

I literally have no idea why this could be happening. Please let me know if I should post more code.

**EDIT:**

AHA! thanks evil otto. It seems I was getting confused with another print statement I had put in before. Now the problem remains: I think I'm not checking for string equality correctly. Here's where **filter** is getting called:

```
    foreach $w( @text_file_words )
    {
            if(filter($w) eq "BAD!")
            {
                    #do something here
            }
            else { print "good!"; }
    }
```

EDIT 2: Nevermind, more stupidity on my part. I need to get some sleep, thanks evil otto.

Comment: post more code, like what's calling `filter`.  Also, add something distinctive to your print to make sure it's not getting confused with some other print, such as `print "-$curse-\n";`

Comment: Please change the title: Perl is not to blame. Your program has a bug, not perl (at least in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$word_to_check = $_;
```

to

```
$word_to_check = shift;
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to collect arguments as an array in perl...

```
sub myFunction{
   ($wordToCheck) = @_; #this is the arg array, if you have more than one arg you just separate what's between the parenthesis with commas. 
}
```